# tensorflow import error only when being in a linux screen session:libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file

Tags: linux, tensorflow

As the title says, I can't import tensorflow only when I open a screen session,but it's all well if I don't open a screen session.I need to run code at the Linux backend but now I don't know what to do to solve the problem.

> ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you double check in your screen session what your LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains?

If it doesn't contain cuda adding it like this solved that problem for me on a normal shell.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I directly add the path and the problem solved.I feel myself ignorant Haha. By the way, how to check what my  LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains?

Comment: Just echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH should give you the contents of the variable.

Comment: Just setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64` didn't work for me, but after `echo`ing the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` value from my normal bash session and adding it to my `.bashrc`, everything works well! Thanks